# Firefox css transition doesn't start when preceded by generated content

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-content

**** Update **
If anyone else encounters this issue, a bug has been filed with Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1011153**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEzc9/3/

Found this today and setup a fiddle for it. The best I can tell right now is that if a target element is preceded by generated content where a transition effect applied, the transition fails to start.

html:

```
"Some text" animates up and down smoothly on hover.
<div>
    <div>
        <span> Some text</span>
    </div>
</div>

"Some text" should animate in and and out. In Firefox, the generated content on div > div:hover::before stops the inital animation.
<div>
    <div>
        <span> Some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid #cc0000;
}
div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
div > div > span {
    bottom: 10px;
}

div > div > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 250ms;
    transition: bottom 250ms;
}
div:last-child > div:hover::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #cc0000;
}
div > div:hover span {
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

I am only seeing this behavior in Firefox. Is there a reason this is happening or does it seem to be a bug in FF?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, I see the same thing using Fx 29.0.1, Win7 x64.

However, for what it's worth, it will work if you create static invisible generated content without the `:hover` pseudo-class, i.e.

```
div:last-child > div::before {
  content:'';
  /* … */
  background:transparent;
}
```

but make it visible on hover, i.e.

```
div:last-child > div:hover::before {
  background:#cc0000;
}
```

[I updated your fiddle to show this.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEzc9/4/)

Comment: It appears that, for whatever reason, Firefox is attempting to transition the existence of generated content, which of course doesn't make sense and would fail (and it's even more bizarre considering only the initial animation fails). Ideally, a transition should only apply to whatever it is declared on, independently of any of its siblings, ancestors or descendants (this includes generated content and any other pseudo-elements).